# Why is this statement correct? &f is of type float**

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I came up on this question:
I have the following instruction

```
float *f = (float*) malloc(5*sizeof(float));
```

and a consequence of this is that

```
&f is of type float**
```

I don't understand why it's like this.

Comment: As an aside, [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) **No.**

Comment: "I don't understand why it's like this." --> What type do you think `&f` is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `f` is `float*`, i.e., a pointer to float. So `&f` is the address of `f`, so its type is address to pointer of float, aka pointer to pointer of float, meaning `float**`.

Answer (score 4):

> I have the following instruction

That thingies are called "statements".

> ```
> float *f = (float*) malloc(5*sizeof(float));
> ```

Don't cast the result of malloc:

```
float *f = malloc(5 * sizeof(float));
```

Even better, determine the size by the pointer you allocate memory for:

```
float *f = malloc(5 * sizeof(*f));  // 5 times sizeof the type, f points to
```

That way you are safe even if the type of `f` would change. No chance of forgetting to change the type after `sizeof`.

Now `f` points to a region of memory large enough to hold five consecutive `float`s; 
`f` is just a variable like all others. Lets take the address of some less scary variable first:

```
int i;
int *ptr = &i;  // &i yields the address of the variable i.
                // The type of i is (int),
                // so a pointer to it is of type (pointer to (int)) -> int*
```

now `f`:

```
float *f = malloc(5 * sizeof(*f));  // or, instead of the result of malloc() simply
                                    // the address of some automatic float variable
float **ptr = &f;  // &f yields the address of the variable f.
                   // The type of f is (pointer to float) -> float*,
                   // so a pointer to it is of type (pointer to (pointer to float) -> float**
```

Comment: Just to be clear, in your example, `ptr == &f`, `*ptr == NULL`, and `**ptr == BAD`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits No, `ptr` is not bad. it holds the address of the variable `f` (regardless the value of `f`). Yes, dereferencing `ptr` once will yield `NULL` and dereferencing it twice dereference the `NULL` pointer which is BAD. I'll change the example to feed it something from `malloc()` to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's start with a simpler example:**

```
int a = 42;
```

in this example `a` in a variable that contains the value `42`.

`&a` is the address of that variable. It can be stored in a pointer:

```
int *b = &a;
```

A variable of type `int *` is a pointer to a variable of type `int`.

**Back to your question:**

In your case, the type of `f` isn't `int` but `float*`. As a consequence, the type of `&f` is `float**`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the type of an expression like

```
&something
```

is `pointer to the type of something`. Since the type of `f` is `*float`, the type of `&f` must be `pointer to *float`, which is written as `**float`.

Conversely, if the type of `something` is `*sometype` (i.e. `pointer to sometype`), the type of `*something` is `sometype`. So if you have

```
float **f;
```

then the type of `*f` is `*float`, and the type of `**f` is `float`.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to an object holds the address of an object. In your case, `f` is a pointer to `float`, which is to say that the value of `f` is the address of a floating-point number (assuming the pointer isn't invalid).
By extension, then `&f` is the address of `f`, which is to say that it's the address of a pointer to `float`, or if you prefer, it's the address of the address of a float, which is the same as saying it is a pointer to a pointer to a floating-point number.